# Adding newuser in Dockerfile

Tags: nginx, permissions, bash, docker

I have the following  dockerfile set up, where i am creating a newuser instead of using the root user.

```
USER root
RUN microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y nginx procps shadow-utils net-tools ca-certificates dirmngr gnupg wget vim\
            && microdnf clean all \
            && rpm -q procps-ng

ENV NGINX_USER="api-gatway" \
    NGINXR_UID="8987" \
    NGINX_GROUP="api-gatway" \
    NGINX_GID="8987"     

RUN set -ex; \
  groupadd -r --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_GROUP"; \
  useradd -r --uid "$NGINXR_UID" --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_USER" 

#To start up NGINX 
EXPOSE 80
USER $SOLR_USER
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

When i exec into my docker container, it still remains as the root user instead of switching to the new user that i have created.

```
uk-:api-gateway m$ docker exec -it 828f6d67a004 /bin/bash 
[root@828f6d67a004 /]#
```

When i check my /etc/passwd file, i can see that the user has been created

```
api-gatway:x:8987:8987::/home/api-gatway:/bin/bash
```

I am able to switch to the new user i have created by doing the su command, shown below:

```
[root@828f6d67a004 /]# su api-gatway
bash-4.4$ whoami 
api-gatway
```

What changes should i make in my dockerfile that when i run my docker image and start the docker container, it starts up as user:api-gatway rather than root?

Answer (score 0):

```
USER $SOLR_USER
```

That variable isn't defined, so presumably Docker is deciding to run with a user *it* thinks is interesting.